# backing bean in jsf scope

Tags: jsf

I am displaying a ProductList, which is made up of Product objects. The Product has attributes of type int, string, string, and int. The data is being pulled from the database and I build a ProductList. The data is in the database, I can see it, but when I display the table, the table shows 0's for the 2 int columns, and blanks in the String columns. Here is the ProductList:

```
@ManagedBean
```

public class ProductList {

```
private ArrayList<Product> allProducts;

public ProductList(){
    allProducts = DatabaseConnector.getAllProducts();
}

public ArrayList<Product> getAllProducts(){
    return allProducts;
}

public void setAllProducts(ArrayList<Product> allProducts){
    this.allProducts = allProducts;
}
```

}

And here is the Product bean:

```
@ManagedBean
```

public class Product {

```
private int id;
private String productName;
private String description;
private int quantity;

public Product() {
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
```

}

Should I change the scope of the beans?

Answer (score 1):

Add scope annotation to your bean , for example `@RequestScoped`   or `@ViewScoped`

otherwise it will be the default scope which is `@NoneScoped`